# Jekyll and Github limit(s)

Tags: html, github, web, content-management-system, jekyll

I'd like to open a website using Jekyll via github. 
It seems to be very simple and practise but is there any limit? For example, is there any limit on page size and website totally size?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in another answer, here’s a soft-limit of 1GB for repositories and a hard limit of 100MB for files[1]. So as long as you stay within those ranges, you should fine. There’s also an Quora post from a GitHub employee a few years ago saying they have no hard limits on GitHub Pages space/bandwidth usage[2], though not sure if that information is still accurate.

[1]https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/

[2]http://www.quora.com/What-are-bandwidth-and-traffic-limits-for-GitHub-pages

Comment: Thanks but it's just confusing. It says 1GB, then that it is "unlimited". Who i should believe to?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Here the page says 1GB limit (https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/) but i'm not sure. If yes, is there a way to increment it?